# Haskell Applying 2 lambda expressions to list of tuples

Tags: haskell, dictionary, lambda

I'm struggling to understand lambda expressions in Haskell.

Here is the problem:

I have a list of tuples `[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)...]` (it can be of any length)

I want to apply two functions f1 and f2 to each tuple in the list, but in such a way that f1 is applied to the first element and f2 is applied to second element of each tuple.

So for example if I had `[(a,b),(c,d)]` I would like to apply f1 and f2 to end up with something like this: `[((f1(a),f2(b)),(f1(c),f2(d))]`.

I think I can use map and lambda expression but I end up with type errors.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with lambda expression and map function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
map (\(x,y) -> (f1 x, f2 y)) list
```

On the lefthand side of the arrow in the lambda expession,
we have the pattern `(x,y)` to match the tuples in your list.
On the righthand side, we write `(f1 x, f2 y)` to create a new tupel,
where the first value is `f1` applied to `x` and the second value is `f2` applied to `y`.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution would be to just

```
map (f1 *** f2) list
```

This is using the fact that `Control.Arrow` provides the `(***)` operator, which says that

```
f *** g = \(x, y) -> (f x, g y)
```